# Magento 1.9 : Error getting collection Model of Catalogrule

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, catalog-rules

I try to get a collection of `Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')` but when I do `Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()` I have an error because can't call a function of boolean.

I do a if:

```
if(Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')) echo "hello"; else echo "no";
```

Always say "no".

Comment: check my answer and tell me what you get?

Comment: I get nothing, empty value

Answer (score 0):

First, try have you got class?

```
 echo get_class(Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule'));die;
```

if you got empty value your module is **inactive**.

Please, active your Module:-

```
app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
```

is your module

```
Mage_CatalogRule
```

is  `<active>true</active>` ?

**OR**

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable modules output
```

Check your module is active?

Comment: I can't call the method getCollection because when I call to Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule') return false.

Comment: But is a core module no?. How can i active this module?

Comment: i just update my answer, please check @str_lml

Comment: Yes, I have all modules active. I have 3 environments, Production, Quality and Local. In production and local i can use Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule') but in Quality i can't

Comment: Yes, I have in the file Mage_All.xml the Mage_CatalogRule active

Comment: can you explain Production, Quality, and Local?  @str_lml

Comment: Yes, Production is the final environment, don't test in this environment, Quality is where the user tests the new functionalities developed in local

Comment: please compare your all extension and database details of your Quality Environment with Production mode

Comment: Ok, but 1 thing, If i do echo get_class(Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')) in a template *.phtml file i have de name of the class. I think the problem is with my file. Is a file for import price rules the wich extends of Mage_Shell_Abstract

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code:**

```
$rules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);

if($rules): 
    echo "hello"; 
else: 
    echo "no";
endif;
```

Comment: i get this: Call to a member function getCollection() on boolean

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
$catalogrules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);

foreach($catalogrules as $rule){
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($rule->getData());
    echo '</pre>';
}

if(count($catalogrules)>0){
   echo "hello"; 
}
else{
   echo "no"; 
}
```

You will get all active catalogPrice rules with rules data.